# string searching with returning matched line in python

Tags: python, string-matching

I am quite new in python.I want to match string in some lines of a file.Let's say,
I have string:

```
british    7
German     8
France     90
```

And I have some lines in a file as like:

```
<s id="69-7">...Meanwhile is the studio 7 album by British pop band 10cc.</s>
<s id="15-8">...And Then There Were Three... is the ninth studio album by the german band Genesis 8 and was released in 1978.</s>
<s id="1990-2">Magnum Nitro Express is a France centerfire fire rifle cartridge 90.</s>
```

I want to get output as like:

```
<s id="69-7">...Meanwhile is the studio <w2>7</w2> album by <w1>British</w1> pop band 10cc.</s>
<s id="15-8">...And Then There Were Three... is the ninth studio album by the <w1>german</w1> band Genesis <w2>8</w2> and was released in 1978.</s>
<s id="1990-2">Magnum Nitro Express is a <w1>France</w1> centerfire fire rifle cartridge <w2>90</w2>.</s>
```

I tried with the following code:

```
for i in file:      
    if left in i and right in i:
        line = i.replace(left, '<w1>' + left + '</w1>')
        lineR = line.replace(right, '<w2>' + right + '</w2>')
        text = text + lineR + "\n"
        continue
     return text
```

But, it also match string from id.eg.

```
<s id="69-<w2>7</w2>">...Meanwhile is the studio <w2>7</w2> album by <w1>British</w1> pop band 10cc.</s>
```

So, is there any way to search string as words not as character so that I can escape `<s id="69-<w2>7</w2>">` ?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Are these `<s>` tags the only tags on the lines, and is there only one per line?

Comment: ah, but based on your demonstrations in the first 2 lines of code snippet 3, i'd expect `France` to match with a `90` somewhere, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ mcnemesis: sorry, it was a typo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use regular expressions to specifically replace only individual words, not word parts.

Something like

```
import re
left='british'
right='7'
i1 = re.sub('(?i)(\s+)(%s)(\s+)'%left, '\\1<w1>\\2</w1>\\3', i)
i2 = re.sub('(?i)(\s+)(%s)(\s+)'%right, '\\1<w2>\\2</w2>\\3', i1)
print(i2)
```

which gives us `'<s id="69-7">...Meanwhile is the studio <w2>7</w2> album by <w1>British</w1> pop band 10cc.</s>'`

And if such approach leads to errors, you can try a more refined code, like

```
import re

def do(left, right, line):
    parts = [x for x in re.split('(<[^>]+>)', line) if x]
    for idx, l in enumerate(parts):
        lu = l.upper()
        if (not ('<s' in l or 's>' in l) and
            (left.upper() in lu and right.upper() in lu)):
            l = re.sub('(?i)(\s+)(%s)(\s+)'%left, '\\1<w1>\\2</w1>\\3', l)
            l = re.sub('(?i)(\s+)(%s)(\s+)'%right, '\\1<w2>\\2</w2>\\3', l)
            parts[idx] = l

    return ''.join(parts)


line = '<s id="69-7">...Meanwhile is the studio 7 album by British pop band 10cc.</s>'
print(do('british', '7', line))
print(do('british', '-7', line))
```

Comment: But, words could be multiple with spaces , numbers etc.So, I took string in array & search them in line.For integer string, I got the above problem.

Comment: Oh, then you have to split line to tags and content.
If you are sure, that `<s>` is the only tag, then it is really simple.

Comment: @ Alex Laskin : yes,  `<s>` is the only tag for each line.

Answer (score 4):

I have something rather complicated, but I wrote it in hurry and for the moment it does the job.

Note that:

- I added 'in France' after **Meanwhile is the studio 7 album by British pop band 10cc**
  and that only **British** is modified
- '1978' in **by the german band Genesis 8 and was released in 1978** isn't modified while the '8' is modified.

That's the reason for which it is complicated.

But I fear that,despite this complication, it won't be exact for all the sentences possible.

Improvement should be done to make that **idi** would always be the correct musical group's name, and not always the first one as it is in this present solution. But it's a hard work without knowing what you exactly want

```
ss ='''british    7
German     8
France     90'''


text = '''<s id="69-7">...Meanwhile is the studio 7 album by British pop band 10cc in France.</s>
<s id="15-8">...And Then There Were Three... is the ninth studio album by the german band Genesis 8 and was released in 1978.</s>
<s id="1990-2">Magnum Nitro Express is a France centerfire fire rifle cartridge 90.</s>
'''




import re
regx = re.compile('^(.+?)[ \t]+(\d+)',re.MULTILINE)




dico = dict((a.lower(),b) for (a,b) in regx.findall(ss))
print 'dico==',dico
print '\n\n'



rogx = re.compile('(<s id="[\d-]+">|</s>\r?\n)')
splitted = rogx.split(text)
print 'splitted==\n',splitted

print '=================\n'

def repl(mat):
    idi = (b for (a,b) in the if b).next().lower()
    x,y = mat.groups()
    if x:
        if dico[idi.lower()]==x:
            return '<w2>%s</w2>' % x
        else:
            return x
    if y :
        if y.lower()==idi:
            return '<w1>%s</w1>' % y
        else:
            return y

rigx = re.compile('(\d+)|(' + '|'.join(dico.keys()) + ')',re.IGNORECASE)

for i,el in enumerate(splitted[0::2]):
    if el:
        print '-----------------------------'
        print '* index in splitted==',2*i
        print '\n* el==\n',repr(el)
        print '\n* rigx.findall(el)==\n',rigx.findall(el)
        the = rigx.findall(el)
        print '\n* modified el:\n',rigx.sub(repl,el)
        splitted[2*i] = rigx.sub(repl,el)


print '\n\n##################################\n\n'

print 'modified splitted==\n',splitted
print
print ''.join(splitted)
```

result

```
dico== {'german': '8', 'british': '7', 'france': '90'}



splitted==
['', '<s id="69-7">', '...Meanwhile is the studio 7 album by British pop band 10cc in France.', '</s>\n', '', '<s id="15-8">', '...And Then There Were Three... is the ninth studio album by the german band Genesis 8 and was released in 1978.', '</s>\n', '', '<s id="1990-2">', 'Magnum Nitro Express is a France centerfire fire rifle cartridge 90.', '</s>\n', '']
=================

-----------------------------
* index in splitted== 2

* el==
'...Meanwhile is the studio 7 album by British pop band 10cc in France.'

* rigx.findall(el)==
[('7', ''), ('', 'British'), ('10', ''), ('', 'France')]

* modified el:
...Meanwhile is the studio <w2>7</w2> album by <w1>British</w1> pop band 10cc in France.
-----------------------------
* index in splitted== 6

* el==
'...And Then There Were Three... is the ninth studio album by the german band Genesis 8 and was released in 1978.'

* rigx.findall(el)==
[('', 'german'), ('8', ''), ('1978', '')]

* modified el:
...And Then There Were Three... is the ninth studio album by the <w1>german</w1> band Genesis <w2>8</w2> and was released in 1978.
-----------------------------
* index in splitted== 10

* el==
'Magnum Nitro Express is a France centerfire fire rifle cartridge 90.'

* rigx.findall(el)==
[('', 'France'), ('90', '')]

* modified el:
Magnum Nitro Express is a <w1>France</w1> centerfire fire rifle cartridge <w2>90</w2>.


##################################


modified splitted==
['', '<s id="69-7">', '...Meanwhile is the studio <w2>7</w2> album by <w1>British</w1> pop band 10cc in France.', '</s>\n', '', '<s id="15-8">', '...And Then There Were Three... is the ninth studio album by the <w1>german</w1> band Genesis <w2>8</w2> and was released in 1978.', '</s>\n', '', '<s id="1990-2">', 'Magnum Nitro Express is a <w1>France</w1> centerfire fire rifle cartridge <w2>90</w2>.', '</s>\n', '']

<s id="69-7">...Meanwhile is the studio <w2>7</w2> album by <w1>British</w1> pop band 10cc in France.</s>
<s id="15-8">...And Then There Were Three... is the ninth studio album by the <w1>german</w1> band Genesis <w2>8</w2> and was released in 1978.</s>
<s id="1990-2">Magnum Nitro Express is a <w1>France</w1> centerfire fire rifle cartridge <w2>90</w2>.</s>
```

### EDIT 1

I eliminated replmodel()

repl() takes the value of the rigx.findall(el)
I added a line **the = rigx.findall(el)** for that

Comment: Thank you! Is there something simple just to ignore `<s id="69-7">` while matching string?

Comment: @Liza Yes, it consists to eliminate parens in the regex' pattern. But if you do that, you can't do join() on the splitted string to obtain the modified string: it will lack the splitters. That's why I keep the splitters and I am obliged to play with indexes (2*i)

Comment: @eyquem, your solution is nice and really exquisite. But it is highly overengineered. Sometimes it is better to have 3 lines of code that handles 99.9% of input, than 50 lines, that handles 100%. One should move to such variants only when the necessity is proved.
+1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use regex.
But in case 'left' and 'right' will always have at least one trailing and leading space then you can use a simple trick(just add leading and trailing space into your pattern):

```
line = file.replace(' ' + left + ' ', ' <w1>' + left + '</w1> ')
lineR = line.replace(' ' + right + ' ', ' <w2>' + right + '</w2> ')
```

Comment: Then you'll get `<w2> 7 </w2>` instead of `<w2>7</w2>`

Comment: @Alex - yes, you are right, i have modified code, but not sure that these spaces will break html(or i am wrong?)